Powershell Invoke-Webrequest keep continue after timeout even with -TimeouSec at 30
I have a powershell script that call website link to get the html code of many website page.
And here's the code :
Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $WebsiteLink -TimeoutSec 30

This code works... Sometimes... In fact the timeout works correctly because I have some proof about this, but once every 100 links the script just won't time out, so the script keep going for hours, without any error message or explanation.
Is it possible to encapsulate the Invoke-WebRequest into a try catch that run the code for 1 minute then if 1 min is passed so the catch part of the code activate and throw an error message. But I can't figure out to do this.
Is this the right way to solve this problem ? Or there is another solution ?

Try using from cmd.exe >Net Stat -a which will give all the open ports and the status.  Most likely a connection did not close and will get a status TIME WAIT.  A WebRequest is an HTTP connection which uses TCP at the transport layer.  TCP is reliable and every message gets an ACK.  Time Wait means the TCP connection when closing did not get an ACK.  Some how in you case the connection closed improperly.  Invoke Request will have a status 200 OK in the response and a 400/500 failure when there is an error.  You should get a response for each request.  You may not be getting a response.

First, is there a way to get the response (200,400,500,...) and Second, is it possible to write a script that throw an error if more than 30 seconds passed without any responses ?

"First, is there a way to get the response (200,400,500,...)":
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $WebsiteLink -TimeoutSec 30
$request.StatusCode

" and Second, is it possible to write a script that throw an error if more than 30 seconds passed without any responses ?"
see: Everything you wanted to know about exceptions
But: "the script keep going for hours, without any error message"
So you have to help in handling exceptions. (Because you do not get one...)
But closing the connection, after you did do what you want to do with the results ($request.Content), using $request.Close might help.

I can't get any status code if my code is blocked at Invoke-WebRequest. Your solution with close could work, but actually it's not possible because there is no Close method or object with this class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.basichtmlwebresponseobject?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0   .
I think I need a try catch that acting as a timeout like it describe in this subject : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/426382/is-there-a-cancel-after-certain-amount-of-time-try-catch-type-of-block .

See also: Avoiding TIME_WAIT, but there is also info on how to shorten the default time that TIME_WAIT takes  (see: "Adjust the .... TcpTimedWaitDelay settings" Settings that can be Modified to Improve Network Performance)
